# An error occurred while processing your request Stimulsoft

Tags: asp.net-core, product, export-to-pdf, stimulsoft

When use  StiNetCoreReportResponse.ResponseAsPdf in the asp.net core mvc in the devlopmentmode
it's work correctly but. when publish project and run in the iis has
Error.
An error occurred while processing your request.
Request ID: 00-75c9603a89a7c54397aafaca1f7c1fff-f3ad5a6da7a4464b-00
.

Comment: You may go to `event viewer` to check if there's any error message. You can also try to use [remote debug](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/remote-debugging-aspnet-on-a-remote-iis-7-5-computer?view=vs-2022) and debug how it worked in IIS.

Comment: Thank you. I Solve it by add    services.Configure<KestrelServerOptions>(options =>
            {
                options.AllowSynchronousIO = true;
            });

            // If using IIS:
            services.Configure<IISServerOptions>(options =>
            {
                options.AllowSynchronousIO = true;
            });
to startup.cs